# Angular Observable Service being called multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that has a method that returns and observable.  I have a component that subscribes to that observable when my it is loaded. I have a console.log in my service to log every time it is called.
When I run my app and look at my console window, I see 3 instances of my logged value.  Why is that? I'm only subscribing to the observable service once.

I actually have a broader question than this simple example where I noticed that when I have several subscriptions to my service, I get even more repeated calls to my functions and the service. Why does that happen given that my assumption is that the purpose of using rxjs and subjects is to have some basic form of state management and the purpose of that being to avoid retrieving data that hasn't changed.

Service:

```
export class ResultService {

  protected id;
  private results$ = new Subject<any>();
  
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService, 
  ) { }

  getResults(id): Observable<any> {
    console.log('get result called in ResultService');
    this.dataService.getResults(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('the value of res in ResultService constructor');
        this.results$.next(res);
      })
    return this.results$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Result Component

```
private subscription$;
@Input() id;

  constructor(
       this.subscription$ = this.resultService.getResults(this.competitionId);
       this.fetchResults(this.competitionId);
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchResults(this.id);
  }
  fetchResults(id){
    this.resultService.getResults(this.id)
      .subscribe((data) => 
      {
        data.forEach(resultElement => {
           //do something
        });
        this.resultList = data;
      })
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.fetchResults(this.id);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe(); //unsubscribe
  }
```

Summary Page html file - has the result component as a child that it passes id

```
  <ion-col size-lg="5">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <app-results-component [id]="id"></app-results-component>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-col>
```

Summary Page ts file

```
  private id: number;
  private dataSub$;
  private resultData : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.competitionId = params['id'];
      this.getData(this.id);
    }
  }

  getData(id) {
    this.dataSub$ = this.resultService.getResults(id);
    this.dataSub$
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.resultData = data;
        this.dosomething(this.resultData);
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataSub$.unsubscribe(); //unsubscribe
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `ngOnChanges()` just for sometime, can you remove `this.fetchResults(this.id)` from `ngOnChanges()` and check how many times it is getting called?

Comment: why are you calling the the method in onChanges?

Comment: Yes @SivakumarTadisetti, you are right. When I commented it out I get only one call. And in fact it also reduced the number of calls in my other component that calls the service.  Why is this?  I was initially using on changes because I wasn't using a Subject.  I need to modify my code to call next when I have new changes so that the new values are emitted and received by subscribers.

Comment: `new changes` -> Might you need to call `this.fetchResults(this.id)` in `ngOnChagnes` only for one `@input()` value change? if that is correct, you need to have a condition to check input's `currentvalue` and `previousvalue`

Comment: Can you update the question with @inputs() and can tell on which input change, you want to call next?

Comment: I added more code. Basically, `this.dosomething(this.resultData);` in the SummaryPage.ts is also being called multiple times.  I would expect it should only be called once.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unsubscribe your subscription.

Sample code:

```
constructor(
    private resultService: ResultService
  ) { }

  subscription$ //declare

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchResults(this.id);
  }

  fetchResults(id){
    this.subscription$ = this.resultService.getResults(this.id)
      .subscribe((data) => 
      {
        data.forEach(resultElement => {
           //do something
        });
        this.resultList = data;
      })
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.fetchResults(this.id);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe() //unsubscribe
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the change, but I still get three calls based on what I see in my console.log.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add if condition `if (changes.id)`
- It seems there's no need to call it in onInit
- You need to unSubscribe the observable

  ```
   private unSub = new Subject();

   constructor(
       private resultService: ResultService
   ) { }

   fetchResults(id){
       this.resultService.getResults(this.id)
           .pipe(
               takeUntil(this.unSub)
           )
           .subscribe((data) =>
           {
               data.forEach(resultElement => {
                   //do something
               });
               this.resultList = data;
           })
   }
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
       if (changes.id) {
           this.fetchResults(this.id);
       }
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
       this.unSub.next();
       this.unSub.complete();
   }
  ```